# Is this a case for foldM?

Tags: haskell

The function sendrecv has the following type signature:

```
sendrecv :: Socket ->
            PSQ.PSQ (String, Integer) POSIXTime ->
            Map.Map (String, Integer) [String] ->
            String ->
            IO  (PSQ.PSQ (String, Integer) POSIXTime,  Map.Map (String, Integer) [String])
```

It takes a socket, a PSQ, a Map and a String and returns a PSQ and a Map.

I would like to call it n times where the socket and the string stay the same but the PSQ and Map get modified, means the modified PSQ, Map should become the input in the next run.

Originally I thought that this may be a perfect case for foldM and tried e.g.

```
(q', m') <- foldM sendrecv (s, q1, m1, "ping") (enumFromTo 1 1000)
```

But apparently this does not work and I fear that I have not yet understood the whole foldM thing or whether there may be a possibility to pass static parameters as well (as with s and "ping") and how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define helper functions

```
iterateM :: Monad m => Int -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
iterateM 0 _ x = return x
iterateM n f x = iterateM (n - 1) f =<< f x

sendRecv' socket string (q, m) = sendRecv socket q m string
```

then you can write

```
(q', m') <- iterateM 1000 (sendRecv' s "ping") (q1, m1)
```

(I'm mildly surprised that something like `iterateM` isn't standard.)

Having said that, here's how to do it using `foldM`:

```
(q', m') <- foldM (flip . const $ sendRecv' s "ping") (q1, m1) [1..1000]
```

or

```
(q', m') <- foldM (\(q, m) _ -> sendRecv s q m "ping") (q1, m1) [1..1000]
```

But I don't think using `foldM` here makes for clear code.

Comment: Can u explain me the lambda you use in the foldM? It gives by the way an error 'No instance for (Num
                       (PSQ.PSQ (String, Integer) POSIXTime,
                        Map.Map (String, Integer) [String]))'

Comment: `foldM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a`, so the function we're passing to `foldM` must have type `a -> b -> m a`, where `a` is the type we're repeatedly transforming, and `b` is the type of each element of the list --- which we're ignoring. But the code I originally put up was ignoring the `a` parameter instead. Oops. I have now changed it so it ignores the `b` parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I think the case for foldM rather than the self-implemented iterateM is here that I am in the Control Monad anyways. However I learned a lot from the iterateM solution!!

Comment: A possible cause for the absence of `iterateM` is that `iterate` produces an infinite list and doesn't take a repetition count argument, so the corresponding monadic combinator would have type `Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> m [a]` and that would not produce anything in many monads. But there's no `iterN :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a` because it's trivially done as e.g. `iterate f x !! n`. That one would have a monadic correspondence, if only it existed. Since it doesn't, no monadic version.