# Is there a "chain" monad function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

## Explain about a "duplicate"

Someone point to [Is this a case for foldM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364379) as a possible duplicate. Now, I have a strong opinion that, two questions that can be answered with identical answers are not necessarily duplicates! "What is 1 - 2" and "What is i^2" both yields "-1", but no, they are not duplicate questions. My question (which is already answered, kind of) was about "whether the function `iterateM` exists in Haskell standard library", not "How to implement a chained monad action".

## The question

When I write some projects, I found myself writing this combinator:

```
repeatM :: Monad m => Int -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
repeatM 0 _ a = return a
repeatM n f a = (repeatM (n-1) f) =<< f a
```

It just performs a monadic action `n` times, feeding the previous result into the next action. I tried some `hoogle` search and some Google search, and did not find anything that comes with the "standard" Haskell. Is there such a formal function that is predefined?

Comment: I did not find it in any *common* packages as well - but [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Monad+m+%3D%3E+Int+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+m+a%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+m+a) at least knows 2 places - in this case I would *replicate* it I guess (maybe `chainM` is a better name though - `replicate` is *given*)

Comment: Does `replicateM` feed in the previous result?

Comment: no it does not - but if I read repeat or replicate I think on different things (just for this reason) - it's really only a comment on the naming - sorry if it caused a missunderstanding

Comment: @Carsten, you inspired my answer with that comment though.

Comment: @dfeuer yeah ;) - btw: that's almost the solution one of the implementations hayoo found choose

Comment: @Carsten, that one that looks almost like mine is a bit backwards. I wonder if it's specially designed for oddball monads like lazy state, or maybe reader. I'm not sure just what's lazy enough to make that make sense.

Comment: @dfeuer I have no clue - I just searched for the signature and had a quick glance - I quite like yours ;)

Comment: @Carsten the docs say that `iterateM` doesn't terminate - wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: @ErikR maybe - I have no time to check this at the moment, so to be sure I'll remove the comment - thanks for the hint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this a case for foldM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364379/is-this-a-case-for-foldm) - the question originally asks about foldM, but the desired signature and implementation are identical.

Comment: @amalloy Two unrelated questions can have identical answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `foldM`, e.g.:

```
import Control.Monad

f a = do print a; return (a+2)

repeatM n f a0 = foldM (\a _ -> f a) a0 [1..n]

test = repeatM 5 f 3
  -- output: 3 5 7 9 11
```

Comment: That is clear enough! Better than writing three lines

Answer (score 10):

Carsten [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227706/is-there-a-chain-monad-function-in-haskell#comment54259993_33227706) `replicate`, and that's not a bad thought.

```
import Control.Monad
repeatM n f = foldr (>=>) pure (replicate n f)
```

The idea behind this is that for any monad `m`, the functions of type `a -> m b` form the Kleisli category of `m`, with identity arrows

```
pure :: a -> m a
```

(also called `return`)

and composition operator

```
(<=<) :: (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c
f <=< g = \a -> f =<< g a
```

Since were actually dealing with a function of type `a -> m a`, we're really looking at one monoid of the Kleisli category, so we can think about folding *lists* of these arrows.

What the code above does is fold the composition operator, flipped, into a list of `n` copies of `f`, finishing off with an identity as usual. Flipping the composition operator actually puts us into the dual category; for many common monads, `x >=> y >=> z >=> w` is more efficient than `w <=< z <=< y <=< x`; since all the arrows are the *same* in this case, it seems we might as well. Note that for the lazy state monad and likely also the reader monad, it may be better to use the unflipped `<=<` operator; `>=>` will generally be better for `IO`, `ST s`, and the usual strict state.

Notice: I am no category theorist, so there may be errors in the explanation above.

Answer (score 2):

I find myself wanting this function often, I wish it had a standard name. That name however would not be `repeatM` - that would be for an infinite repeat, like `forever` if it existed, just for consistency with other libraries (and `repeatM` is defined in some libraries that way).

Just as another perspective from the answers already given, I point out that `(s -> m s)` looks a bit like an action in a State monad with state type `s`.

In fact, it is isomorphic to `StateT s m ()` - an action which returns no value, because all the work it does is encapsulated in the way it changes the state. In this monad, the function you wanted really is `replicateM`. You can write it this way in haskell although it probably looks uglier than just writing it directly.

First convert `s -> m s` to the equivalent form which `StateT` uses, adding the information-free `()`, using `liftM` to map a function over the return type.

```
> :t \f -> liftM (\x -> ((),x)) . f
\f -> liftM (\x -> ((),x)) . f :: Monad m => (a -> m t) -> a -> m ((), t)
```

(could have used `fmap` but the Monad constraint seems clearer here; could have used `TupleSections` if you like; if you find do notation easier to read it is simply `\f s -> do x <- f s; return ((),s)` ).

Now this has the right type to wrap up with StateT:

```
> :t StateT . \f -> liftM (\x -> ((),x)) . f
StateT . \f -> liftM (\x -> ((),x)) . f :: Monad m => (s -> m s) -> StateT s m ()
```

and then you can replicate it n times, using the `replicateM_` version because the returned list `[()]` from `replicateM` would not be interesting:

```
> :t \n -> replicateM_ n . StateT . \f -> liftM (\x -> ((),x)) . f
\n -> replicateM_ n . StateT . \f -> liftM (\x -> ((),x)) . f :: Monad m => Int -> (s -> m s) -> StateT s m ()
```

and finally you can use `execStateT` to go back to the Monad you were originally working in:

```
runNTimes :: Monad m => Int -> (s -> m s) -> s -> m s
runNTimes n act =
  execStateT . replicateM_ n . StateT . (\f -> liftM (\x -> ((),x)) . f) $ act
```

Comment: This is very similar to my answer. The monadic interface of `StateT` is overkill, since you never look at the results. Suppose you take `newtype StateM s m = StateM {runStateM :: s -> m s}` . Then `instance Monad m => Monoid (StateM s) where {mempty = pure; mappend (StateM f) (StateM g) = StateM (f >=> g)}`. Now you can `foldMap StateM` to string together a bunch of `s -> m s` functions!

Comment: Absolutely. There are monoids everywhere. `f ()` is a monoid under `*>`, `s -> m s` is a monoid under `>=>`, and so on. The point of my answer was simply to relate the question to the standard library function `replicateM` because at first glance it seems to be applicable, and then it isn't. The observation being "Well, it is `replicateM` - just for a slightly different Monad".

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.